# How can i get total size of all partition with batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I need to get sum of all partition size on windows with batch script.
for this i write a script that only can echo size of each partiton, but when i want to sum them, i got error "Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision."

my code without sum:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('WMIC LOGICALDISK WHERE "drivetype=3" GET Size^|findstr [0- 
9]') do echo %%a
```

my code with sum:

```
@echo off
SET total=0
for /f %%a in ('WMIC LOGICALDISK WHERE "drivetype=3" GET Size^|findstr [0-9]') do (
SET /a total+=%%a
)
echo %total%
```

and output :

```
Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
0
```

I can't find any solution for my problem.

Actually i want to know total size of disk on a windows machine and free size on it. I don't need size of each partition separately. finally i need a short script to calculate and return it to my zabbix monitoring remotely

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Dear Stephan I can't understand this post, can you explain on my code ?

Comment: To simplify, your numbers have too many digits to be able to work with `Set /A` arithmetic. There are some workarounds without seeking the help of other utilities, programs, or languages, but those are very convoluted and not really worth the effort. We are not here to write your code for you according to the reference material, that unfortunately is your job.

Comment: In addition to the above, can you please explain the purpose/end goal of your task. Are you wanting to determine the total size allocated to partitions on one specific device, on all of them as totals per device, on all of them together as one total, the unallocated sizes of each device, the total unallocated sizes across all devices, or something else. The biggest issue I can see is that you're not going about your task in the right way regardless of the `Set /A` limited functionality.

Comment: Actually i want to know total size of disk on a windows machine and free size on it. I don't need size of each partition separately. finally i need a short script to calculate and return it to my zabbix monitoring remotely

Comment: You need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58639069/edit) such that it clearly shows and explains, the task you've posted in the comments, because it is clearly different from that which you have in your question area.

Answer (score 0):

you don't require script you can use zabbix aggregate functions to achieve.

check the screenshot to achieve.

[image]

Example
Total disk space of host group 'MySQL Servers'.

grpsum["MySQL Servers","vfs.fs.size[/,total]",last]

grpavg[["Servers A","Servers B","Servers C"],system.cpu.load,last]